# Storybook: pass props defined in the contexts file to components

Tags: vue.js, storybook, storybook-addon-specifications

How can I pass props defined in the `contexts` file to components in my stories? Docs does not make this clear: https://www.npmjs.com/package/@storybook/addon-contexts

I am using vue.

Is there a working example of someone using addon-contexts?

Comment: You can take a similar approach to this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60460548/how-to-switch-locale-with-storybook-in-vue-js-project-via-the-storybook-addon-c.

Answer (score 1):

I m looking too for something similar and i have founded this link: https://monorepo-git-add-addon-contextsvue-i.storybook.now.sh/examples/vue-kitchen-sink/?path=/story/addon-contexts--languages

Maybe it can help ;)